# How to force going to bookmark to refresh Angular page?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code which enables the page to track state on the page in the URL variable:

template:

```
<div>id = {{id}}</div>
<div>uid = {{uid}}</div>
<div>score = {{score}}</div>

<button ng-click="changeNumber()">change</button>
```

controller:

```
mainApp.controller('pagestateController', function ($scope, $log, $location) {
    urlVariables = $location.search();
    $scope.id = urlVariables.id === undefined ? 0 : urlVariables.id;
    $scope.uid = urlVariables.uid === undefined ? 0 : urlVariables.uid;
    $scope.score = urlVariables.score === undefined ? 0 : urlVariables.score;

    $scope.changeNumber = function() {
        $scope.urlManagerChangeVariable('id', Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) + 20);
        $scope.urlManagerChangeVariable('uid', Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) + 20);
        $scope.urlManagerChangeVariable('score', Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) + 20);
    };

    $scope.urlManagerChangeVariable = function(name, value) {
        urlVariables = $location.search();
        urlVariables[name] = value;
        $location.search(urlVariables);
        $scope.id = urlVariables.id;
        $scope.uid = urlVariables.uid;
        $scope.score = urlVariables.score;
    }
});
```

It works fine as each time you click the button, the three URL variables change and so if the user makes a bookmark or copies the URL, then when returning to the page, all state can be rebuilt.

However, at least in Firefox, if I:

- make two bookmarks with different URL variables
- switch between them back and forth
- the page is not rebuilt

`Ctrl`-bookmark or `Shift`-bookmark will work but opens up a new window/tab, or after I go to the new bookmark, I can reload the page it the numbers on the page will then reflect the URL variables.

**Is there a way that I can force Angular to reexecute the controller when the user switches from one bookmark to the other?**

### Andendum

I am using ui-router and added the following `.config` section, but with no effective

```
mainApp.controller('pagestateController', function ($scope, $log, $location) {
    //$state.forceReload(); //produces endless loop
    //$state.reload(); //produces endless loop
    //$state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true}); //produces endless loop
    urlVariables = $location.search();
    $scope.id = urlVariables.id === undefined ? 0 : urlVariables.id;
    $scope.uid = urlVariables.uid === undefined ? 0 : urlVariables.uid;
    $scope.score = urlVariables.score === undefined ? 0 : urlVariables.score;

    $scope.changeNumber = function() {
        $scope.urlManagerChangeVariable('id', Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) + 20);
        $scope.urlManagerChangeVariable('uid', Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) + 20);
        $scope.urlManagerChangeVariable('score', Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) + 20);
    };

    $scope.urlManagerChangeVariable = function(name, value) {
        urlVariables = $location.search();
        urlVariables[name] = value;
        $location.search(urlVariables);
        $scope.id = urlVariables.id;
        $scope.uid = urlVariables.uid;
        $scope.score = urlVariables.score;
    }
}).config(function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$state', function($delegate, $stateParams) {
        $delegate.forceReload = function() {
            return $delegate.go($delegate.current, $stateParams, {
                reload: true,
                inherit: false,
                notify: true
            });
        };
        return $delegate;
    });
});
```

Comment: are you using ui router? if yes i added this to my config which allows me to use $state.forcereload() to reload the current page .config(function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$state', function($delegate, $stateParams) {
        $delegate.forceReload = function() {
            return $delegate.go($delegate.current, $stateParams, {
                reload: true,
                inherit: false, 
                notify: true
            });
        };
        return $delegate;
    });
}) since i had my problems with $location i switched to ui router with $state

Comment: Yes, I'm using ui-router. I added the `.config` section (above) but calling forceReload just puts the browser into an endless loop. Am I calling it right?

Comment: I also tried it calling it from the `mainController` but got the same result.

Comment: ok, I got it to work in a click event, but (a) it forceReload() erases all URL variables, and (b) I don't need this in a button, but I need it somehow always load the page as one is accustomed to when a bookmark is clicked, but it seems if a bookmark is clicked and the based URL is the same, then it will load. However, if I am one a completely different website and I click a bookmark, then it loads.

Comment: this is weird i can call this where ever i want i use it in controller, view via button and in a directive so this is kinda weird, my approach for the url would be that you would have to save those urlparameters somehow and add after the forcereload i am not really sure if you can use the ui-routers rule to keep your url params have a look at it https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing

Comment: When i think about it maybe the inherit parameter from the .config set to false, could change that but i never tried that since i dont use any url parameters at all

Comment: I found this which could be of use for you if you define your optional parameters in ur states u can make use of them either in the forcereload or in you controller so the url paramter reset shouldnt be an issue http://benfoster.io/blog/ui-router-optional-parameters and checkout the last section of the above posted link (urlmatcher)